# browser caching via htaccess for WP+ woocommerce shop

Tags: javascript, wordpress, caching

[the code as picture shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sj77k.png)

did I make wrong?
I am working on WP+WOOcommerce shop, with admin authentication login and social login plugin

Comment: what's the issue?

Comment: 500 internal server error.

Comment: the whole website can't not open

Comment: ok, so removing that `.htaccess` code makes your website running?

Comment: after removing that, it is working again